# Undoing localization nib file Xcode

Tags: localization, xcode4.5, nib

I am working in localizing an app for French and Spanish. We localized some nib files but recently decided we are going to change some elements in the nib files programmatically rather than creating a version of each nib file for each language.

That being said, I want to undo the localization for a nib file so I uncheck the Spanish and French Localization for the nib file in File Inspector view. The problem is that English language is also localized and when I uncheck this option the nib file is deleted from Project Navigator view so the original unlocalized nib file is gone...

Is there a way to undo localization for a specify file without losing it?

Thank you.